# how to dispaying '✔' dynamically in jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, thickbox

I am using Unicode value `"\u2713"`  to display '✔' a tick mark in a row of table(like static way inside .jsp), now I need to display '✔' Dynamically, whenever I click on one <kbd>upload</kbd> button in my `thickbox` using `java-script` through `ajax` request.

Comment: Have you tried anything? please paste your code

Comment: FYI, javascript != java != jsp

Answer (score 2):

Please google first.

in HTML use this `&#10004;`

in javascript use `write()`

```
document.write('&#10004;');
```

OR

```
domDIV.innerHTML = '&#10004;';
```

Comment: You can also just do `document.write('✔')`, `.innerHTML = '✔'` or just use `✔` in the html in the first place

Comment: yes but in that case the html file would not be a simple text file i guess.

Comment: It would still be a plain text file, just encoded in an unicode encoding which is even supported by the infamous windows notepad

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML entities `&#10003;` or `&#10004;​` to display ✔